# Angularjs $resource url path

Tags: angularjs, service, resteasy

it is my first time trying to pass a method to url with parameters and ran into some problems. So essentially, I am passing string value from html page to server (I'm using restEasy framework) via controllers and services, but I keep getting the 404 not found error.

So the code is as follows.

html code snippet which calls the controller:

```
<div class="container">
<a href="#notificationGroup" class="btn btn-success" role="button">Create New Distribution List</a>
<div class="panel panel-primary center-block" style="margin-bottom: 10px;margin-top: 10px">
    <div class="panel-heading">
    </div>
    <div id="searchfield">
        <form id="searchFieldForm" autocomplete="on">
            <h4>Code: <input type="text" data-ng-model="code" class="biginput" name="code" >
                Name: <input type="text" name="name" data-ng-model="name"  class="biginput">
                <button data-ng-click="search(name, code)" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                    Search</button>
            </h4>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

controller:

```
myApp.controller('SearchController',
function($scope,SearchCollection,$location) {
    $scope.search = function(name, code) {
        $scope.distributionLists = SearchResultCollection.search(name, code);
        $location.path('/list');
    }
});
```

service:

```
myApp.factory('SearchResultCollection', function($resource) {
return $resource('../api/foo/:name/SearchSingle/:code',
    {name:'@name', code:'@code'}, {
        search : {method: 'GET',
            isArray: true}
    })
});
```

The error i got is :

```
GET http://localhost:9080/api/foo/SearchSingle 404 (Not Found)
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Double check your `$resource` path. It seems that the `:code` parameter is missing.

Comment: yep, I realized that too. But what could be possibly causing this? isn't what I'm doing now the right way of passing parameters?

Comment: You didn't declare the `:code` parameter in your factory. Also, the `:name`  parameter is missing.

Comment: Where did you assign it?

Comment: do you mean that beside {name:'@name', code:'@code'}, I'll need to declare code and name in the factory? Sorry I'm pretty new to this. Could you please provide me with an example?

Comment: Can you show more of your html codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
myApp.controller('SearchController',
        function($scope, SearchCollection, $location) {
            $scope.search = function(name, code) {
                $scope.distributionLists = SearchResultCollection.search({name: name, code: code});
                $location.path('/list');
            };
        });

myApp.factory('SearchResultCollection', function($resource) {
    return $resource('../api/foo/:name/SearchSingle/:code', {name: '@name', code: '@code'}, {
        search: {method: 'GET', isArray: true}
    });
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer alberto. After I changed the code, it gives me this error: TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object